# Datatables, changing row colors after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am editing a datatable using ajax and fnOpen function, to add  rows based on a certain condition. This is how my code looks:

```
$('#table tr').each(function(){
    id = this.id.substr(4);
    var result2;
    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    $.post('file.php', {id: id}, function(result) {
        result2 = result;
    }); 
    if (result2 .length > 0) {
        oTable.fnOpen( this, 'Notes: ' + result2, "info_row");
    }
});
```

The above is perfectly working, inserting the data in the new row. However, after that is done, I would like to change the newly added row and make it the same color as the previous one. How can I access from here the datatables options, and do that? How can I know the class of the previous row? I am very new to datatables and a bit lost sometimes!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a class of the current row in the using the:

```
$('#table tr').each( function () {
                        var rowClass = $(this).attr("class");
```

When you call fnOpen, a third parameter is a class that will be assigned to the TD element containing the injected row. Currently you are always putting hard-coded "info_row" class, but if you assign some dynamic value that depends on the rowClass you can style it to be in the same color as the current row.

Jovan

Answer (score 0):

They way you're adding my details row is blowing my mind; if you're pulling that off, setting a few classes should be easy. ;-)

Assuming the new row is in the DOM by the end of the function, it should be fairly simple. Within the same function once the DOM addition has been done (therefore 'this' is the table row currently in the .each() iterator):

```
var $this = $(this) // might as well do this caching near the beginning of the function
var prevClass = $this.prev().class();
$this.addClass(prevClass);
```

I'm sure you can see that you don't really need to make a variable "prevClass" but this is just how I like to keep things straight and organized. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

First, i don't think you want to call `$.ajaxSetup` in the each -- you are changing the global ajax settings every time you go thru the `each`.  Do that once when your app starts *if* you want whatever you do in the setup to apply to all ajax calls.

Second, just change your `post` call to modify the row color in the callback

```
$.post('file.php', {id: id}, function(result) {
    result2 = result;
    // modify row color here
});
```